# Mixpanel Query Events with properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, analytics, mixpanel

I'm tracking referral source for how users ended up on a specific page

```
$mixpanel.track('Page View', 
  'doctor_profile_id': doctor_uuid,
  'patient_profile_id': currentUser.uuid,
  'referral_source': 'News Feed', // this could be ['Search', 'Recommendations'] etc
});
```

I'd like to be able to query the Mixpanel API and get a count of `Page View` specifying a parameter such as `doctor_profile_id` and recieve a response with a count of page views and also counts for the various referral sources.

I was looking at the [event](https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/data-export-api#events-default) endpoint but it looks like you can only get back 'Page Views'. You could accomplish this task by exporting the CSV but that's far from ideal.

Is this the right approach to solving this problem or am I using mixpanel incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the [segmentation endpoint](https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/data-export-api#segmentation-default)